# Can git rebase record the SHA1 of the original commits like git cherry-pick -x does?

Tags: git

For some purposes it would be very helpful if git rebase could record a reference (SHA1) to the original commit in the newly created commit, similar to what git cherry-pick does with the -x option.

Is there a way to get git to do that?